# Permissions for installing Windows Updates

Tags: windows, security, group-policy, wsus, windows-update

we are administering a set of servers and have a lot of people to accomplish this. In the last months there were accidentally installed updates on our machines by some of our domain admins.

Now we want to disable the ability for admins to install those updates on our servers and allow it for a specific set of users in a group. Does anyone know a method to accomplish this? I've searched through the group policy and security settings but didn't find a possibility for this.

Thanks in advance for all your helpful answers :)

Comment: Have you considered using an update management product like `WSUS`?  Once the nodes are configured to receive updates from WSUS, no matter who uses the machine will only receive approved updates.  You can easily control who has access to manage the update server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Force the update via WSUS and nothing else and secure on the server hosting WSUS the local administrator group and the WSUS administrator's group.

> There are two security groups that are set up for WSUS: WSUS
>   Administrators and WSUS Reporters. WSUS Administrators can perform any
>   WSUS task, while WSUS Reporters have read-only access (view server
>   settings, get reports, and so on). Make sure that the only people in
>   the WSUS Administrators group are the ones who need to perform
>   administrative tasks.
>
> If users do not have appropriate permissions for the WSUS console,
>   they receive an "access denied" message when trying to access the WSUS
>   console. You must be a member of the Administrators group or the WSUS
>   Administrators group on the server on which WSUS is installed in order
>   to use the WSUS console.

Be advised if WSUS is installed on a Domain Controller, that tip does not work.

> If WSUS is installed on a domain controller, only a member of the
>   Domain Administrator group can use the WSUS console.

Comment: This won't prevent you from installing non wsus approved updates.

Comment: @JimB Yes if you manually download the update, but the OP specified an admin error, not a backstabbing

Comment: Oh, I thought they were going to WU and getting updates.

Comment: This answer only works if you *trust* your Admins. As an Admin if I delete the value **UseWUServer** from the Registry key `HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU` WSUS is gone and Windows Update is back. Hmmm....

Comment: @Twisty If you dont trust your admin better fire them. The first rule is, they did an error, you prevent the error to happen again, but if they circle around the protection, then they deserve to be fire. They can even format the c:\, and a field technician can dump water on the storage too if he want.. The issue is trust, if you dont trust an admin, then dont give them server admin status at first (like JimB's answer state), and revoke his id to get access to the server room

Comment: @yagmoth555 I agree with you, though how to handle such a situation obviously varies from one case to the next. My point is that this answer *requires* one to trust their Admin. That doesn't make the answer bad. But if the OP really wants to *disable the ability for admins to install those updates* then it's only fair to point out this answer technically doesn't do that. In fact +1 because your answer is nonetheless useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you're an Admin, you own the box.  It's not possible to prevent an admin from installing updates.  This sounds more like a process problem than a technical problem.  Another solution is to remove domain admins as actual admins, and keep those identities secured.  By keeping those identities secure you can have better operational control.  You can then use JEA for day to day admin tasks.